# Why is it impossible to call static methods on Nullable<T> shorthands?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax-error, nullable

I thought `T?` is just a compiler shorthand for `Nullable<T>`. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/):

> The syntax `T?` is shorthand for `Nullable<T>`, where `T` is a value type.
>   The two forms are interchangeable.

However, there is a little (insignificant) difference: Visual Studio doesn't allow me to call static methods on shorthands:

```
bool b1 = Nullable<int>.Equals(1, 2); //no error
bool b2 = int?.Equals(1, 2); //syntax error "Invalid expression term 'int'"
```

Why? Is there any reason for this limitation?

Comment: It's a syntax thing. The parser can't figure out the `?.`

Comment: This is a good question, though I don't know what would be the meaning of that, What would we try to test with Nullable<int>.Equals(1, 2)? (I'm not being mean, is a real question)

Comment: Starting with C# 6, `?.` used as null-conditional check, hence it is syntax error. The situation maybe different when using earlier version which doesn't recognize `?.` as single operator.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto `int` is definitely not an expression nor a variable, so it cannot be null-conditional check. There is no ambiguity.

Comment: Nope. not limited to C#6 doesn't work in 5 either.

Comment: Yes, its difference occurs in the left side assignment. In C# 6 it is syntax error due to null-conditional check between int & expression, where in version 5 or earlier it even doesn't fit as `Nullable<T>` definition or just a ternary operator.

Comment: The short-hand syntax is valid in *declarations*.  But this is an expression, the expression parser in C# does march to a different drummer.   The curly brace languages in general do support a lot of features in expressions, not in the least by making an expression also a valid statement.  It now goes looking for a lot more, operators are now valid.  Which makes ? ambiguous with the conditional operator and the elvis operator, no white space required.

Comment: @HansPassant The language spec mentions explicitly that [*“the two forms can be used interchangeably”*](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/types.md#nullable-types). If this is really a limitation of the expression parser and this is not actually backed by the spec, then it’s a bug in the compiler.

Comment: `Nullable<T>` has no static methods of its own. This is just a really complicated way of writing `Object.Equals`. So while the question is mildly interesting, it's not like it limits you in any way whatsoever -- just write what you mean, which, in all cases, will boil down to using `Object`. Otherwise you might mislead the reader into thinking some "specialized" or "efficient" implementation is getting called, which is not the case.

Comment: This works:  `(int?).Equals(1, 2);`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your MSDN quote echoes §4.1.10 of the C# 5.0 specification:

> A nullable type is written `T?`, where `T` is the underlying type. This syntax is shorthand for `System.Nullable<T>`, and the two forms can be used interchangeably.

But “interchangeably” is an oversimplification. It’s true that `T?` means `System.Nullable<T>`, but as you’ve discovered, you can’t use `T?` everywhere that you can use `System.Nullable<T>`. In particular, the kind of *member-access* (§7.6.4) in your example requires a *simple-name* (§7.6.2):

> [§7.6] Primary expressions include the simplest forms of expressions.
>
> *primary-expression:*
>     *primary-no-array-creation-expression*
>     *array-creation-expression*
>
> *primary-no-array-creation-expression*
>     *literal*
>     *simple-name*
>     *parenthesized-expression*
>     *member-access*
>     ...
>
> [§7.6.2] A *simple-name* is either of the form `I` or of the form `I<A1, ..., AK>`, where `I` is a single identifier and `<A1, ..., AK>` is an optional *type-argument-list*.
>
> [§7.6.4] A *member-access* is either of the form `E.I` or of the form `E.I<A1, ..., AK>`, where `E` is a *primary-expression*, `I` is a single identifier and `<A1, ..., AK>` is an optional *type-argument-list*.

`Nullable<T>` is a *simple-name* and `T?` isn’t, so the former compiles whereas the latter doesn’t.

Why did the C# language designers require a *member-access* expression to use a *simple-name* as opposed to any *type*? I suppose only they can say for sure, but maybe this requirement simplified the grammar: In an expression, the compiler can assume that `?` is always the conditional (ternary) operator instead of possibly a nullable type specifier.

In hindsight though, this was a fortunate choice that allowed C# 6.0 to add the `?.` operator without possibly breaking existing programs. For example, consider this pathological example:

```
struct S
{
    public bool Equals(int x, int y) { return false; }
}

class C
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        S? S = new S();
        Console.WriteLine(S?.Equals(1, 1)); // "True" or "False"?
    }
}
```

Should `S?.Equals` be parsed as `Nullable<S> . Equals`, a call to the `Equals` static method of class `Object`? Or should it be parsed as `S ?. Equals`, a null-conditional call to the `Equals` instance method of variable `S`? Because `S?` isn’t a *simple-name*, it’s unambiguously the latter.

Answer (score 0):

While you're right about the syntax, the Equals method can be called from the default type using Nullable type as parameters.

You can try this unit test with whatever value you want :

```
int? i = 4;
int? j = null;
Assert.AreEqual(Nullable<int>.Equals(i, j), int.Equals(i, j));
```

Comment: That's because both method calls are just calling out to `object.Equals` which takes two `object` instances.  These are both identical to `object.Equals`.

Comment: You're right. I was just pointing out that there is no need to try to call 'int?.Equals()'.